# Realm swift thread safe variable

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, thread-safety, realm

I am new to Realm and I am wondering if it is good idea to store primary key of object in View controller and object as stored property.

```
class VC: ViewController{
    public var id:Int!
    private var customer:Customer{
        get{
            return DBO.loadCustomer(for: id)
        }
    } 
}
class DBO{
    public static func loadCustomer(for id: Int) -> Customer{
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return realm.object(ofType: Customer.self, forPrimaryKey: id)!
    }
}
```

I am assuming that this because of this my app will be thread safe, because every time thread will try to access customer it will fetch object from db. But I wonder if this is efficient for single object and array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

As of Realm 2.2 you could use thread-safe references (see [here](https://realm.io/news/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/)):

> Now, you can create thread-safe references for all types that were
>   previously thread-confined within a Realm, and passing objects between
>   threads becomes a simple, three-step process:
>
> 1. Initialize a ThreadSafeReference with the thread-confined object.
> 2. Pass that ThreadSafeReference to a destination thread or queue.
> 3. Resolve this reference on the target Realm by calling
>      Realm.resolve(_:). Use the returned object as you normally would.

And a code sample, from the source above:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let person = Person(name: "Jane") // no primary key required
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(person)
}
let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)
DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.myApp.bg").async {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  guard let person = realm.resolve(personRef) else {
    return // person was deleted
  }
  try! realm.write {
    person.name = "Jane Doe"
  }
}
```

But, your approach should also work fine.

Comment: `ThreadSafeReference`s are meant to be short-lived. As the documentation states: "Prefer short-lived ThreadSafeReferences as the data for the version of the source Realm will be retained until all references have been resolved or deallocated."